# Saving to database creates multiple entries

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2, vaadin14

I am writing an application that manages tasks and associated notes. This is a Spring Boot application that uses Vaadin for the UI and (currently) an H2 database on the backend accessed via Hibernate.

The application consists on a "main" page that displays tasks. Clicking on a task allows for viewing details, as well as a button to route to another page to allow viewing and editing of associated task notes.

The project can be found in github at https://github.com/jgagnon44/tasks-app. I can also post code snippets here, although I'm not really sure what I should include. Comment to ask for items.

I'm seeing behavior I can't explain. When I'm in the notes list view and I add a new note, save it and add another and save that, I find the first note has been duplicated. The duplicate has a timestamp close to the timestamp of the second note saved. If I were to add a third new note, this time the first and second note will be duplicated, resulting in a total of 3 first notes, 2 second notes and the one third note I just added.

I've added debugging statements at critial code points and am printing the entities involved at these points.

I've also included a log with annotations below to illustrate some of what's happening.

Can someone give me an idea what's going on and what I need to do to correct the problem?

Log transcript:

```
NOTE: Task-1 has two existing TaskNote items associated with it (note-1 and note-2).

>>>>> Main page.
>>>>> Select Task-1 in grid.
>>>>> Click Edit Notes button.

[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:02:25.340 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.refresh(NotesListView.java:100) - PARENT: null
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:02:25.358 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.refresh(NotesListView.java:100) - PARENT: Task [hashcode=-523436836, title=Task-1, description=null, type=RECURRING, state=OPEN, priority=HIGH, notes=[TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2]], dateClosed=null, dateDue=null, dateStarted=null, dateCompleted=null]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:02:25.361 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.lambda$7(NotesListView.java:104) - NOTES: [TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2]]

>>>>> Notes List page.
>>>>> Click Add button.
>>>>> Enter note 3.
>>>>> Click Save button.
>>>>> Note 3 appears in notes list.

[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:05.709 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.saveNote(NotesListView.java:159) - PARENT: Task [hashcode=-523436836, title=Task-1, description=null, type=RECURRING, state=OPEN, priority=HIGH, notes=[TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2]], dateClosed=null, dateDue=null, dateStarted=null, dateCompleted=null]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:05.709 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.saveNote(NotesListView.java:160) - NOTE: TaskNote [hashCode=1422869202, note=Note 3]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:05.731 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.refresh(NotesListView.java:100) - PARENT: Task [hashcode=-523436836, title=Task-1, description=null, type=RECURRING, state=OPEN, priority=HIGH, notes=[TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=1422869202, note=Note 3]], dateClosed=null, dateDue=null, dateStarted=null, dateCompleted=null]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:05.735 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.lambda$7(NotesListView.java:104) - NOTES: [TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=333570519, note=Note 3]]

>>>>> Click Add button.
>>>>> Enter note 4.
>>>>> Click Save button.
>>>>> Note 4 appears in notes list. Notice that a second note 3 appears with a similar timestamp as note 4.

[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:27.617 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.saveNote(NotesListView.java:159) - PARENT: Task [hashcode=-523436836, title=Task-1, description=null, type=RECURRING, state=OPEN, priority=HIGH, notes=[TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=1422869202, note=Note 3]], dateClosed=null, dateDue=null, dateStarted=null, dateCompleted=null]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:27.618 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.saveNote(NotesListView.java:160) - NOTE: TaskNote [hashCode=1422869203, note=Note 4]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:27.628 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.refresh(NotesListView.java:100) - PARENT: Task [hashcode=-523436836, title=Task-1, description=null, type=RECURRING, state=OPEN, priority=HIGH, notes=[TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=1422869202, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=1422869203, note=Note 4]], dateClosed=null, dateDue=null, dateStarted=null, dateCompleted=null]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:27.634 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.lambda$7(NotesListView.java:104) - NOTES: [TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=333570519, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=-1887191816, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=-1221858374, note=Note 4]]

>>>>> Click Back button.
>>>>> Main page.
>>>>> Select Task-1 in grid.
>>>>> Click Edit Notes button. There are five notes.

[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:44.434 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.refresh(NotesListView.java:100) - PARENT: null
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:44.439 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.refresh(NotesListView.java:100) - PARENT: Task [hashcode=-523436836, title=Task-1, description=null, type=RECURRING, state=OPEN, priority=HIGH, notes=[TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=333570519, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=-1887191816, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=-1221858374, note=Note 4]], dateClosed=null, dateDue=null, dateStarted=null, dateCompleted=null]
[INFO ] 2021-04-14 15:03:44.444 com.fossfloors.taskapp.ui.view.NotesListView.lambda$7(NotesListView.java:104) - NOTES: [TaskNote [hashCode=-331664091, note=note-1], TaskNote [hashCode=-823479065, note=note-2], TaskNote [hashCode=333570519, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=-1887191816, note=Note 3], TaskNote [hashCode=-1221858374, note=Note 4]]
```

Comment: Seems like you're adding them to a `List` or other `Collection` and saving the whole collection every time. But we don't have the code, so that's the best guess

Answer (score 0):

I had a peek into your git, and I think the issue is that you save a `Task` that has a cascading relation to a *List* of `TaskNote`, but you pass an outdated `Task` instance that does not have all the `TaskNotes` that you previously saved.

Make sure that you update `parentTask` after saving, so it keeps track of it's current (persisted!) TaskNotes. This should make sure that it doesn't duplicate the relations in the DB on subsequent saves. You already do perform a `refresh()` on the view after a save, BUT still you forget to update parentTask instance there.
Here is how your `refresh` method could be improved:

```
private void refresh() {
    logger.info("PARENT: {}", parentTask);
    if (parentTask != null) {
      Optional<Task> optTask = taskService.findById(parentTask.getId());
      optTask.ifPresent(task -> {
        logger.info("NOTES: {}", task.getNotes());
        this.parentTask = task;    // UPDATE PARENTTASK INSTANCE HERE!!
        grid.setItems(task.getNotes());
      });
    } else {
      grid.setItems();
    }
  }
```